Missing files and weird permissions issues when using NFS as k8s StorageClass
I've been having some very strange issues on my kubernetes cluster recently, often relating to files disappearing, never being created and permissions issues.  For example, I have a script that installs WordPress using helm.  If I install it using the NFS as my StorageClass, it consistently fails to install the default theme and doesn't serve a default page. I get an error when I try to install a theme because the directory isn't writeable for some reason.  Even though the pods were up and all happy, I gave it another 12 hours to finish installing or whatever but it never did.  Same missing files, same permissions errors.
These issues go away completely when I switch my StorageClass to hostpath instead of NFS.  Wordpress installs, the default theme and page are immediately served, I'm able to install other themes and actually use it.
Can NFS slowness cause that?  It's also weird to me that it's consistently failing in the same way every time, I would expect it to be more random about what gets written and what doesn't.  And how the heck does NFS slowness cause this unwriteable directory?
Hardware-wise, all k8s nodes are connected by CAT5 cables directly to the router.  The router and node NICs are all gigabit, so I realize I'm losing some speed with the CAT5 cables (got some CAT6 in the mail).  The disk I'm sharing over NFS is a 5400 RPM HDD.  There's room for improvement of course but I'm not convinced hardware upgrades will fix this.
It just doesn't make sense to me that NFS slowness would cause issues with being able to write to a directory or the same files to be missing in every install.  Is upgrading my HDD and/or cables likely to solve this problem?  Any other suggestions or opinions appreciated.

So I switched my NFS to a different disk and all issues have gone away.  I ran fsck on the old disk and found 0 problems. I've switched to only using the old disk for large files and so far all seems to be fine.
